Basic knowledge to review economic legislation from an economist's perspective
I am a conservative and want to learn how to analyze economic legislation from an economist's perspective are there any good small books and guides on this matter?

Why is being a conservative relevant for your question? We do not need to know your identity, there isn't special conservative economics

@1muflon1 I don't see the need to be so aggressive, obviously economics isn't separate based on political grounds, but many people could question or comment as to why I want to know to begin with when many other analysis exist. But, I simply don't fully trust these analysises, because of special interest on both sides. Hence, by stating I am a conservative people assume since I don't trust mainstream media I as my motive.


I am not being aggressive, I am just explaining you this since you are not aware. 2. No it isn't you are thinking of Political Economy which is not the same as Economics. You can read principles of microeconomics by Mankiw, who is Republican in US (so I guess conservative), and Economics by Krugman (who always supports democrats) and you will not be able to point out to me any substatntive difference between those two books, they both cover basics of economics and they are both the same, if I would remove the covers from the book you wouldnt be able to tell by reading who is Rep and who Dem


@1muflon1 okay, but do these books help with analysis and using math when pertaining to legislation and fiscal policy like tax cuts etc.

Those books are very basic but they do help. For example those books teach you how to analyze VAT taxes, but they do not talk much about income taxes and capital taxes etc (because those are more complex topics), if you want to learn how to do an analysis of income taxation then what you need to do is as follows: Learn basic economics (supply and demand elasticities etc you can use those books I mentioned for that), then you need to learn basic Public Economics (e.g. see Stiglitz Public Economics), then if you want to perform serious analysis not just undergraduate playing it the sandbox

you want intermediate public economics by hindricks and myles, once you know how to analyze effects of taxes, to see if the tax is good for your political constituency/ideological beliefs you want to study Political Economy and Public Choice. For public choice assuming you already studied everything I suggested you can go directly to advance textbooks such as Mueller Public Choice III and actually Political Economy is not very deep field so you can just go with something like Political Economy by May et al

@1muflon1 thank you for answering my question are pdfs provided on both books also would you recommend early 1900s books they're usually shorter on these type of matters.

No because those books will be incredibly outdated. You do not need to read every single chapter of the books I suggested, you need to master basics of supply and demand, understanding elasticities and basics of taxation and then you can skip some other stuff that is less relevant such as behavioral economics that is not used that much in theories of optimal taxation. For the higher level books you can just focus on topics you care about (e.g. income tax, capital tax... )

@1muflon1 k thanks
